# Skype version not supported any more in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: skype

I have Skype Beta version, and since last week it doesn't work. Whenever I open it, it says this version is not supported anymore. Maybe I need to unistall this older version of Skype and install a new one?

What should I do?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current Linux/Ubuntu version of Skype from the Skype web site.  Download it, follow installation instructions, and (if necessary) change any launchers to point to the newly installed version.